# Count the diagonal elements from (x,y) position

Tags: c, math

Consider a matrix `m*n` starting from (0,0) I want to create a logic to count the diagonal elements which should be applicable for `0<m,n<10^6`.
Example:
Consider,
m=2,n=3

```
A)At 0,0 the only diagonal element will be 1,1
```

but

```
B)
for 0,1 their will be two digonal elements
1)1,0
2)1,2
```

I am not able to make a generic solution to calculate the diagonal elements for any x,y position in matrix.
Can anyone give me a direction to go ahead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly count without looping it as follows

```
//Make the index to normal position
x++;
y++;
//If your x,y is (0,0) it will become (1,1)

//Calculate the rows and columns before and after the current position.
rowsB4 = x - 1 ;
rowsAft = m - x ;
colsB4 = y - 1 ;
colsAft = n - y ;

//Now you can find the lesser number in each of the directions and add it total diagonals

totalDiag = 0 ;

//Left Up
temp = (rowsB4 < colsB4) ? rowsB4 : colsB4 ;
totalDiag += temp ;

//Left down
temp = (rowsAft < colsB4) ? rowsAft : colsB4 ;
totalDiag += temp ;

//Right Up
temp = (rowsB4 < colsAft) ? rowsB4 : colsAft ;
totalDiag += temp ;

//Right down
temp = (rowsAft < colsAft) ? rowsAft : colsAft ;
totalDiag += temp ;
```